# System.OutOfMemoryException unresolved after increasing max server memory

Tags: sql, sql-server, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

I am new at this so please bear with me.

Earlier I was trying to import a very large CSV file using bulk insert without any batchsize, kilobytes_per_batch or row_per_batch arguments. I then hit upon the following error:

An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

I worked around this problem by splitting the CSV and importing it in chunks. As a result I ended up having two separate tables in SQL 2016 Server Management Studio. These two tables contain values from the CSV that had been split. They therefore have the same columns, column size, and data types. I decided to use a union all query to combine them. When I did the error came back. I then decided to increase the max server memory to 5 GB, which I think should be more than enough. However when I retried the union all query the error came back again anyways. My computer has 8 GB of RAM in total. I am using windows 10 64 bits and an x64 based processor.

The table's properties look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[indivs16] (
    [Cycle] [char] (4) NOT NULL,
    [FECTransID] [char] (19) NOT NULL,
    [ContribID] [char] (12) NULL,
    [Contrib] [varchar] (50) NULL,
    [RecipID] [char] (9) NULL,
    [Orgname] [varchar] (50) NULL,
    [UltOrg] [varchar] (50) NULL,
    [RealCode] [char] (5) NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Amount] [int] NULL,
    [Street] [char] (3) NULL,
    [City] [varchar] (30) NULL,
    [State] [char] (2) NULL,
    [Zip] [char] (5) NULL,
    [Recipcode] [char] (2) NULL,
    [Type] [char] (3) NULL,
    [CmteID] [char] (9) NULL,
    [OtherID] [char] (9) NULL,
    [Gender] [char] (1) NULL,
    [Microfilm] [varchar] (18) NULL,
    [Occupation] [varchar] (38) NULL,
    [Employer] [varchar] (38) NULL,
    [Source] [char] (5) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here is the query I ran for the union:

```
SELECT * FROM Indivs16000
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Indivs16001
```

Here is a screenshot of how I do my queries:

[image: pic]

Comment: First, your database has its own memory settings, which would not change if you plug more memory into the server. Second, you should be able to import CSV in batches into the same table. This is the preferred approach for large files.

Comment: @Ashalynd I did try to import the batches into the same table as well. However after importing a certain number of batches into the same table the error would come back.

Comment: How did you do that? What is the size of that file and what was the batch size? What are your database settings? Also, what is the table structure, does it have any indices defined?

Comment: One easy approach could be writing a python (perl, or whatever language you can use) script which would copy rows from one table into another. Or read the rows from the original file and write into a table with that script. And most probably, someone has already written a similar one :)

Comment: The size of the original file was 3.67 GB. Three of the batch sizes were 1 GB. The remaining three were 0.37 GB, 0.37 GB, and .09 GB. I don't know what you mean by database settings. I will post what the table structure was. I don't know what indices are.

Comment: @Ashalynd Wouldn't I just encounter the memory problem again anyways if I did that? I mean that is what I technically did anyways during the import. I kept putting the data into the same table until it couldn't handle it anymore. Then I put the rest into a second table.

Comment: Not if you use small batches (e.g. 100 or 1000 rows per batch). It will take some time (you have to pay with something, either with memory or with time spent) but eventually finish.

Comment: 1 GB is enormous batch size, in any case. The idea of batches is that they are relatively small chunks.

Comment: Regarding the out-of-memory for too large table - I assume that the table is not stored in memory (unless that's how your database is defined). Otherwise you really want to check how your database is persisted.

Comment: @Ashalynd The data is all already in SQL, just in two separate tables. I no longer have a problem with importing the data. I think the problem is that the table is too large as you suggested. How do I check to see if the two tables are stored in memory? Does the memory optimizer have something to do with that?

Comment: I suspect it is the OutOfMemory exception on your computer. I guess you are doing select * from Table1 union all select * from table2 in SSMC. The query gets output into the output window until it hits the out of memory exception on your PC.

Comment: @cha I am using the query you decribed. I will edit my question to reflect that.

Comment: Why do you want to view all records (how many of them BTW?) on the screen? What is the purpose of it?

Comment: @cha the purpose of having all that data in one table is so I can run queries with it and find patterns in campaign finance by comparing it with other tables. I will also have to perform a join with another table later on so I can prevent doublecounting of the same event.

Comment: use the query: `insert into Indivs16000 SELECT * FROM Indivs16001;` then everything will be in `Indivs16000`. Then you can drop the `Indivs16001` and use just one table for queries. However, do not use `SELECT * FROM Indivs16000`. Instead, restrict your query with `SELECT TOP 100`

Comment: @cha I will try that and tell you the results.

Comment: @cha it worked and now all my data is in one table. However I am concerned about having to restrict myself in all future queries involving this table. Won't it be very difficult to check for redundancies accross the board if I have to do that? Also please post your response as an answer so I can give you credit along with your suspicions as to the cause of the outofmemory exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been very simple if you have used import/export utility, even with bulk insert you can use batches and insert into same table. However its not end of world you can try again.

Comment: I don't think you understand the problem. The import is fine. The issue is that now I cannot work with the huge tables in my database due to the memory error.

Comment: i do understand the problem and that's why suggested to import into one table, you still can combine these two tables. I am certain that the  requirement is not to read that hefty data in one go.

Answer (score 0):

That error looks like a .NET error, not a SQL Server error.

How are you querying?  If you are querying using `System.Data.DataTable` you are running out of memory on the client side because it is loading it all into memory.

You should instead use `IDataReader` to query the data, which will stream through the data "firehose" style where you read one-way through the data record at a time, so you only have a few thousand records fetched into client memory at a time-- no matter how big your table is or how many records your `SELECT` statement is returning.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am new at this so I might have a hard time following you. I am not sure what you mean by "How are you querying?". In hopes that it will answer your question I will add a screenshot of where I make my queries. I do not know what IDataReader is but it could be the solution to my problem. Can you show me how to query with IDataReader or give me a link that will explain it to a beginner? In the meantime I will look up information on it. I hope querying using IDataReader is not to different from how I normally do it.

Comment: It appears that I would need a program called Microsoft Visual Studio to do this. I don't have  that and using it looks extremely complicated. Is there an alternative method of using IDataReader?